# Intel NUC DN2820FYKH, No Sound!

Tags: 12.04, 13.10, sound, intel

I have Ubuntu 13.10 Installed on this machine. It is a Celeron N2820 Processor which is a fairly new chip, just wondering what I should do to troubleshoot this issue? I have no prior experience with Ubuntu and have searched around but I am not sure if it a hardware issue, driver issue or a software issue. Any advice would be appreciated. Also, if I do a fresh install/downgrade to 12.04 could this possibly solve the issue?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing Pulse Audio Volume Control ,gives the HDMI audio options, needed:
From:https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/paman/

hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, this did answer the quesiton, to make it even easier for a someone, these are the steps I took:

Add the following groups to your account: audio, pulse, pulse-access, video, voice

1. Open a terminal window and run the following:
2. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/alsa-daily`
3. `sudo apt-get update`
4. `apt install oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms`
5. Restart System.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing sound plugin.:

```
     sudo apt-get install libmp3lame0
```

also

```
     sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

I hope this helps.Post if doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you, I will do this when I get home. I will post the results afterwards.

Comment: I tried both options with no luck. The audio through the headphone jack works fine but nothing through HDMI.

Comment: Also I have the following: **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC283 Analog [ALC283 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: ID 2882 Digital [ID 2882 Digital]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

Comment: And my Kernel is: 3.11.0-15-generic #25-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 30 17:22:01 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux